# Pyspark group dataframe within time interval

Tags: datetime, group-by, python-datetime, pyspark

I have a PYSPARK dataframe which is sorted ('timestamp' and 'ship' ascend):

```
+----------------------+------+
|        timestamp     | ship |
+----------------------+------+
| 2018-08-01 06:01:00  |    1 |
| 2018-08-01 06:01:30  |    1 |
| 2018-08-01 09:00:00  |    1 |
| 2018-08-01 09:00:00  |    2 |
| 2018-08-01 10:15:43  |    2 |
| 2018-08-01 11:00:01  |    3 |
| 2018-08-01 06:00:13  |    4 |
| 2018-08-01 13:00:00  |    4 |
| 2018-08-13 14:00:00  |    5 |
| 2018-08-13 14:15:03  |    5 |
| 2018-08-13 14:45:08  |    5 |
| 2018-08-13 14:50:00  |    5 |
+-----------------------------+
```

I want to add a new column to the dataframe called 'trip'. A trip is defined as a ship-number which sails within 2 hours from the start of the ship-record in the dataframe. If within the two hours the ship number changes, a new trip number should be added to the dataframe column 'trip'.

Desired output looks like:

```
+----------------------+------+-------+
|        timestamp     | ship | trip  |
+----------------------+------+-------+
| 2018-08-01 06:01:00  |    1 |    1  | # start new ship number
| 2018-08-01 06:01:30  |    1 |    1  | # still within 2 hours of same ship number
| 2018-08-01 09:00:00  |    1 |    2  | # more than 2 hours of same ship number = new trip
| 2018-08-01 09:00:00  |    2 |    3  | # new ship number = new trip
| 2018-08-01 10:15:43  |    2 |    3  | # still within 2 hours of same ship number
| 2018-08-01 11:00:01  |    3 |    4  | # new ship number = new trip
| 2018-08-01 06:00:13  |    4 |    5  | # new ship number = new trip
| 2018-08-01 13:00:00  |    4 |    6  | # more than 2 hours of same ship number = new trip
| 2018-08-13 14:00:00  |    5 |    7  | # new ship number = new trip
| 2018-08-13 14:15:03  |    5 |    7  | # still within 2 hours of same ship number
| 2018-08-13 14:45:08  |    5 |    7  | # still within 2 hours of same ship number
| 2018-08-13 14:50:00  |    5 |    7  | # still within 2 hours of same ship number
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

In Pandas it would be done as such:

```
dt_trip = 2 # time duration trip per ship (in hours)
total_time = df['timestamp'] - df.groupby('name')['timestamp'].transform('min')
trips = total_time.dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)//(dt_trip*3600)
df['trip'] = df.groupby(['name', trips]).ngroup()+1
```

How would this be done in PYSPARK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using **`window functions`**, **`row_number()`**, **`collect_list()`**, and an **`incremental sum`** over conditions created.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1=Window().partitionBy("ship").orderBy(F.unix_timestamp("timestamp")).rangeBetween(-7199, Window.currentRow)
w2=Window().partitionBy("ship").orderBy("timestamp")
w3=Window().orderBy("ship","timestamp")

df.withColumn("trip", F.sum(F.when(F.row_number().over(w2)==1, F.lit(1))\
                       .when(F.size(F.collect_list("ship").over(w1))==1, F.lit(1))\
                       .otherwise(F.lit(0))).over(w3)).orderBy("ship","timestamp").show()

#+-------------------+----+----+
#|          timestamp|ship|trip|
#+-------------------+----+----+
#|2018-08-01 06:01:00|   1|   1|
#|2018-08-01 06:01:30|   1|   1|
#|2018-08-01 09:00:00|   1|   2|
#|2018-08-01 09:00:00|   2|   3|
#|2018-08-01 10:15:43|   2|   3|
#|2018-08-01 11:00:01|   3|   4|
#|2018-08-01 06:00:13|   4|   5|
#|2018-08-01 13:00:00|   4|   6|
#|2018-08-13 14:00:00|   5|   7|
#|2018-08-13 14:15:03|   5|   7|
#|2018-08-13 14:45:08|   5|   7|
#|2018-08-13 14:50:00|   5|   7|
#+-------------------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check tomorrow. What is the -7199 in the range about?

Comment: unix_timestamp is timestamp in seconds, so 7200 seconds = 2 hours.window range is from 0-7199 which is total 7200 seconds